# HTTP Error 500.19

Tags: iis, http-error

I moved previously published application from IIS-6 to IIS-8 on new windows server 2012R2

new application is giving me below error.

```
Server Error in Application "application name"

HTTP Error 500.19 – Internal Server Error

HRESULT: 0x8007000d

Description of HRESULT
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
```

can anyone guide me how to resolve this error.

Comment: Anything in the event viewer?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by changing application pool CLR version to 2.* from 4.*, as it was written in previous version of the .net framework.